# GoogleDrive web rest query

Tags: android, rest, drive

for some reason, this query works:

```
                   FileList result = drive.files().list()
                .setQ("mimeType != 'image/jpeg'")
                .setPageToken(pageToken)
                .execute();
```

but this:

```
        FileList result = drive.files().list()
                            .setQ("appProperties has { key='owner' and value='owner_test' }")
                .setPageToken(pageToken)
                .execute();
```

ps: im sure the file has the property OWNER with value owner_test

this second query using addProperties, keep returning error:

```
400 Bad Request
{
"code": 400,
"errors": [
{
     "domain": "global",
     "location": "q",
      "locationType": "parameter",
       "message": "Invalid query",
     "reason": "invalid"
 }
],
"message": "Invalid query"
}
```

i cant build queries using another properties or anything different than "mimeType ..." =(

**i FOUND THE SOLUTION ABOUT THE NAME**, DONT USE NAME, instead use title "title contains ....", v2 you use name, but for the new drive api v3, you must use title... anyway other properties have problems, i will change the query  to 'appProperties has { key='key' and value='value' }'